# Is it possible to implement move operator+/operator-/operator* for class of Matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix, move, operator-keyword, memory-efficient

I am thinking on how can i define a class of real matrices NxN with the operations Add (Subtract) and Multiply. I am looking for Efficient Memory Usage.

```
class Matrix {
private:
    std::size_t _size_n;
    double **_pMatrix;

public:
    Matrix(const size_t n);

    ~Matrix();

    double &operator()(size_t, const size_t);

    double operator()(size_t, const size_t) const;

    size_t size_n() const { return _size_n; }
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Matrix &);

Matrix operator+(const Matrix&, const Matrix&);
Matrix operator-(const Matrix&, const Matrix&);
Matrix operator*(const Matrix&, const Matrix&);
```

Comment: it is not clear what you want to move where, or what copies  you want to avoid. Parameters are references already.

Comment: btw you should take care of the [rule of 3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), or use `std::vector` instead of a `double**`

Comment: @idclev463035818: `(a+b)+c` creates 2 temporaries(a+b, and final sum), whereas `(a+b)+=c` would create only one (but syntax is not fine).

Comment: @Jarod42 I had to think twice to see why moving helps, but I still think that the question could be more clear, so I didn't delete the comment

Comment: @idclev463035818: in fact, it is not moving, but we avoid to allocate a new matrix by reusing one parameter.instead of `auto res = tmp + var2; return res;`, we might do `tmp += var2; return tmp;`. But I agree that it is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can have additional overloads

```
Matrix/*&&*/ operator+(const Matrix&, Matrix&&);
Matrix/*&&*/ operator+(Matrix&&, const Matrix&);
Matrix/*&&*/ operator+(Matrix&&, Matrix&&);
```

To reuse memory of one of the temporary.

They can all be implemented with `Matrix& operator += (Matrix&, const Matrix&)`
by changing the order as + is symmetrical. `operator -` would require dedicated code.

Another way to optimize memory is to use [expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) instead of computing directly the result.

It has its drawback about lifetime issue (especially with `auto`) though.

Comment: do i need to do something like this? 
Matrix operator+(const Matrix& left, Matrix&& right) { right += left; return right; }?
and does += then have to be specific?

Comment: For +, it is OK, but for -, you cannot change order like that ;-)